# Efficiently encode videos which consist of audio and multiple images / frames at specific time stamps

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, images, encoding

As a follow up question to [Efficiently encode videos which consist of audio and only one image / frame](https://superuser.com/questions/1601826/efficiently-encode-videos-which-consist-of-audio-and-only-one-image-frame) :

I have a video that is only a few images and an audio track. It is very large and I would like to make it smaller. Since there is only few images/frames, I would think it would be more efficient if only this one frame would be saved and just shown, instead of having a copy of the image in every frame. How can I make such a video with ffmpeg on linux?

So far I have used the command

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4

which greatly reduced the size. According to https://community.geniusvision.net/platform/cprndr/ta/gvrapidans/entry-h.c1wrrauu27jg.html it does it by analysing what is background and what is foreground and it does not repeat redundant information in the background. In my case this means that everything is background.

However, it takes SO much time for the transformation and I have a couple of other videos I would like to transform. Is there a way to speed up the process or choose a different command?

For example I am thinking, whether I could tell ffmpeg at which part in time which image should be started to be used (instead of the previous). Then it would not need to encode the rest. Or maybe I can tell H.265 that everything is background and make the encoding faster that way? However, I think it might be nice not to use H.265 in order to have faster decoding when playing the video.

Comment: You are using crf which means constant rate factor, this is exactly what you don't want. Instead enable two pass then ffmpeg will hopefully detect that most of the necessary bitrate is very low as there are no or only minimal changes because of compression artefacts.

Comment: No, CRF already does this, by looking ahead at future frames. What you want is to enable variable frame rate mode and use a filter like mpdecimate to reduce duplicate frames. Additionally, set a higher keyframe interval, but only as a last resort.

Comment: @Robert: Could you please provide the exact command? I was not able to find what you referred to in the man pages.

Comment: @Gyan: Could you please provide the exact command? I was not able to find what you referred to in the man pages.